# angular app is slow in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova

We have created one cross platform app using angular and ionic. This is working very smoothly in Android but when it comes to iOS then it becomes very slow. We are using localForage to store data. We are fetching the data from localForage on every screen and on some screens we are storing data to localForage. Do anyone one know what might be the reason for this slowness?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you tried to profile your app? Do you use animations? Is it slow in safari on iOS as well?

Comment: We are not using any animations.
We are not able to test it in safari iOS since we are using ngCordova plugin for salesforce authentication which is not working in browsers. 

Regarding profiling we have not done it yet. I will try it once and see what is causing the issue. Thank you for this(profiling) hint. 
Thank you

Comment: Checkout this plugin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc it might help you with emulating it in browser

Comment: Thank you Maurycy. I will try this.